# An empty string in a column of type "TIMESTAMP", caused unreadable

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

This is a third party database file, so I cannot change it schema.

I'm using `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter.Fill` method to get The entire data in target table.

But when it read to a data row will thorw a `FormatException`:`"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"`.

I checked this table and finds that this row was stores an empty string under a column of type "TIMESTAMP".

I tried to change this cell to a normal data or null and will not throw exception again, so I confirmed this issue is caused by this empty string.

I didn't find a valid solution anywhere, so I asked this question.
Has anyone ever solved this problem?

Comment: I have to agree here - `""` is not a valid date/time - so: don't store that? store null if you mean null...

Comment: @Flithor Why is there an empty string there?

Comment: @john I said this is a third party database... so I don't know why and how they stores an empty string, but i cannot fill this table now

Comment: @MarcGravell I just want to read this database instead of store anything in it...

Comment: did you try to use any DBMS software to browse int that database?

Comment: @MarcGravell stupid question: can't he change the SQL he's using to read data and use that to select NULL instead of an empty string?

Comment: @RedWei I said I checked that table - so i must use some way to browse this database...

Comment: @FrancescoB.What I need to say is - I don't know the schema of the table, so I can't know what column it has, nor can I know its type.

Comment: SQLIte doesn't really have strong column data types. Change your `DataTable` to store the column as a string and deal with it after reading it in.

Comment: If nothing else works: load the data into your model as `string`, and post-process it in-memory to whatever you need

Comment: maybe if you can use try catch, whenever it throws `FormatException` you get the null data?

Comment: @NetMage You shound think "I don't know anything about this database". Due to the requirements, I must adapt to multiple third-party databases, so I can't set all possible will error columns to String type

Comment: @Flithor If you don't know anything about the database, how can you expect to use `Fill`? How do you know the meaning of columns? Are you writing a GP database tool like SSMS or Access?

Comment: @NetMage hmmmm, yeah, somewhat similar. And `Fill` can auto create a table schema same as target database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being confirmed by the SQLite.NET development team, they think this is WAD (Works As Designed).

So I can only deal with this possible problem by other ways when read the database.

```
//...
using (var comm = new SQLiteCommand($"SELECT * FROM {tableName}", conn))
{
    using (var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var dt = d.Tables[tableName];
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var r = dt.NewRow();
            for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                try
                {
                    var val = reader.GetValue(i);
                    r[i] = val;
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    if (dt.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                        r[i] = DateTime.MinValue;
                    else
                        throw;
                }
            dt.Rows.Add(r);
        }
    }
}
```

(PS: I still think this is a bug, because `Fill` method should not throw this exception when filling the table)